# Menú lateral izquierdo no se adapta con propiedad con flex

Tags: html, css

estoy creando mi primera aplicación web básica y tengo problemas con el frontend, no soy muy buena con este tema.

Tengo 2 menús: una barra lateral izquierdo (Sidebar) y una barra de navegación (navbar). Quiero que mi menú sidebar se coloque en el lado izquierdo y se oculte y muestre con un botón, pero no puedo acercarme a ese efecto. Os dejo una foto para que vean cómo quiero que se vea el menú.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero lograr este mismo efecto aquí el link donde conseguí el condigo del sidebar
https://bootstrapious.com/tutorial/sidebar/index.html

```js
    // Muestra y oculta el menu lateral izquierdo
    $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
        $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
    });
```

```css
/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

.wrapper {
    display: flex; /* Propiedad Flex quitar */
}

#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    background: #7386D5;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

    #sidebar.active {
        margin-left: -250px;
    }

    #sidebar .sidebar-header {
        padding: 20px;
        background: #6d7fcc;
    }

    #sidebar ul.components {
        padding: 20px 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
    }

    #sidebar ul p {
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    #sidebar ul li a {
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        display: block;
    }

        #sidebar ul li a:hover {
            color: #7386D5;
            background: #fff;
        }

    #sidebar ul li.active > a,
    a[aria-expanded="true"] {
        color: #fff;
        background: #6d7fcc;
    }

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul.CTAs {
    padding: 20px;
}

    ul.CTAs a {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 0.9em !important;
        display: block;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

a.download {
    background: #fff;
    color: #7386D5;
}

a.article,
a.article:hover {
    background: #6d7fcc !important;
    color: #fff !important;

/* unvisited link */
a:link {
    color: black;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: black;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
    color: blue;
}




#RenderBody {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;

    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

i.fas,
i.fab {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    font-size:25px;
}

a:hover {
    color: violet;
}



.fa-fish {
    color: red;
}

.fa-frog {
    color: red;
}

.fa-user-ninja.vanished {
    opacity: 0.0;
}

.fa-facebook {
    color: rgb(59, 91, 152);
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - test</title>

    <environment include="Development">
        <!-- <Libreria Font Awesome> -->
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/55c228f8f9.js"></script>

        <!-- <Libreria TadaTable> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
        <!-- <Libreria Boostrap> -->
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    </environment>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper" style="display: flex;">
            <!-- Sidebar  -->
        <nav id="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-header">
                <h3>Bootstrap Sidebar</h3>
            </div>

            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                <p>Dummy Heading</p>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Home</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Pages</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="list-unstyled CTAs">
                <li>
                    <a href="https://bootstrapious.com/tutorial/files/sidebar.zip" class="download">Download source</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar" class="article">Back to article</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- Sidebar  -->
        <!--Navbar-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark" id="TopNavBar">
            <div class="container">
                <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
                    <i class="fas fa-align-left"></i>
                    <span>Toggle Sidebar</span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Inicio</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" id="TopUL">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a href="/Home/About" class="nav-link">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a href="/Home/Contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!--/.Navbar-->

        <div class="container">
            <div class="arrow">
                <div id="RenderBody">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">

<h1> This is the Index </h1>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="py-5">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <form class="form-inline"></form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4 col-md-1 align-self-center">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fab fa-facebook-square fa-3x"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4 col-md-1 align-self-center">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fab fa-twitter-square fa-3x"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4 col-md-1 align-self-center">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-3x"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 mt-3 text-center">
                            <p>© Copyright 2019  - All rights reserved.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

        <environment include="Development">
            <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <!-- <Libreria TadaTable>-->
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
            <!-- </Libreria TadaTable>-->
            <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        </environment>
        <environment exclude="Development">
            <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                    crossorigin="anonymous"
                    integrity="sha384-tsQFqpEReu7ZLhBV2VZlAu7zcOV+rXbYlF2cqB8txI/8aZajjp4Bqd+V6D5IgvKT">
            </script>
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                    crossorigin="anonymous"
                    integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd">
            </script>
            <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        </environment>

        @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
        </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: El sidebar funciona bien, el problema es que la navbar no está en el lugar correcto, deberías sacarla del flexbox, puedes ponerla antes del `div.wrapper`, por ejemplo, aunque seria mejor ponerla como en el ejemplo y que estuviera dentro del `div.container`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el código he comentado un par de cambios que hice conservando el resto de tu código.

**Eliminado `style="display: flex;"`**

**Agregado este div `<div id="content">`**

```js
// Muestra y oculta el menu lateral izquierdo
    $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
        $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
    });
```

```css
/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

.wrapper {
    display: flex; /* Propiedad Flex quitar */
}

#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    background: #7386D5;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

    #sidebar.active {
        margin-left: -250px;
    }

    #sidebar .sidebar-header {
        padding: 20px;
        background: #6d7fcc;
    }

    #sidebar ul.components {
        padding: 20px 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
    }

    #sidebar ul p {
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    #sidebar ul li a {
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        display: block;
    }

        #sidebar ul li a:hover {
            color: #7386D5;
            background: #fff;
        }

    #sidebar ul li.active > a,
    a[aria-expanded="true"] {
        color: #fff;
        background: #6d7fcc;
    }

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul.CTAs {
    padding: 20px;
}

    ul.CTAs a {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 0.9em !important;
        display: block;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

a.download {
    background: #fff;
    color: #7386D5;
}

a.article,
a.article:hover {
    background: #6d7fcc !important;
    color: #fff !important;

/* unvisited link */
a:link {
    color: black;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: black;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
    color: blue;
}




#RenderBody {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;

    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

i.fas,
i.fab {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    font-size:25px;
}

a:hover {
    color: violet;
}



.fa-fish {
    color: red;
}

.fa-frog {
    color: red;
}

.fa-user-ninja.vanished {
    opacity: 0.0;
}

.fa-facebook {
    color: rgb(59, 91, 152);
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - test</title>

    <environment include="Development">
        <!-- <Libreria Font Awesome> -->
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/55c228f8f9.js"></script>

        <!-- <Libreria TadaTable> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
        <!-- <Libreria Boostrap> -->
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    </environment>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper"><!--eliminado style="display: flex;"-->
            <!-- Sidebar  -->
        <nav id="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-header">
                <h3>Bootstrap Sidebar</h3>
            </div>

            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                <p>Dummy Heading</p>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Home</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Pages</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="list-unstyled CTAs">
                <li>
                    <a href="https://bootstrapious.com/tutorial/files/sidebar.zip" class="download">Download source</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar" class="article">Back to article</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- Sidebar  -->
        <!--Navbar-->
        <div id="content"><!--Agregado este div-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark" id="TopNavBar">
            <div class="container">
                <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
                    <i class="fas fa-align-left"></i>
                    <span>Toggle Sidebar</span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Inicio</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" id="TopUL">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a href="/Home/About" class="nav-link">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a href="/Home/Contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!--/.Navbar-->

        <div class="container">
            <div class="arrow">
                <div id="RenderBody">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">

<h1> This is the Index </h1>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="py-5">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <form class="form-inline"></form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4 col-md-1 align-self-center">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fab fa-facebook-square fa-3x"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4 col-md-1 align-self-center">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fab fa-twitter-square fa-3x"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4 col-md-1 align-self-center">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-3x"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 mt-3 text-center">
                            <p>© Copyright 2019  - All rights reserved.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

        <environment include="Development">
            <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <!-- <Libreria TadaTable>-->
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
            <!-- </Libreria TadaTable>-->
            <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        </environment>
        <environment exclude="Development">
            <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                    crossorigin="anonymous"
                    integrity="sha384-tsQFqpEReu7ZLhBV2VZlAu7zcOV+rXbYlF2cqB8txI/8aZajjp4Bqd+V6D5IgvKT">
            </script>
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                    crossorigin="anonymous"
                    integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd">
            </script>
            <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        </environment>

        @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
        </div>
        </div>
        </body>
</html>
```